# Using google charts framework doesnt work when called using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-visualization

im using the [google charts libaries](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/chart/interactive/docs/index.html), just testing the [example code](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start.html) in my server everything goes well. BUT, if i put the code in one page, lets call it example.php, if i call example.php from another page using ajax, like:

```
    $.ajax({ url: 'stats-render.php', data: {ref: $(this).attr('id')}, type: 'post', success: function(d) {
        $('div.stats-data').html(d);
    }});
    $('div.stats-data').html('<center><img src="css/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loader_IMG" /><br>Rendering your stats</center>');
1000);
    });
```

It does work, obviously there is a problem when i call the example via ajax and not when i call it directly. Any ideas?

Comment: @GuillaumeCisco No, it just dont load

Comment: Can you tell me what are the html headers sent after your ajax call ?
You can know it easily using the 'network' tab from opera dragonfly.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
(anonymous function)
e.extend.globalEvaljquery-1.7.min.js:2
e.extend.globalEvaljquery-1.7.min.js:2
brjquery-1.7.min.js:2
e.extend.eachjquery-1.7.min.js:2
f.fn.extend.domManipjquery-1.7.min.js:4
f.fn.extend.appendjquery-1.7.min.js:3
f.fn.extend.htmljquery-1.7.min.js:4
$.ajax.successprofile.php:97
f.Callbacks.njquery-1.7.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.o.fireWithjquery-1.7.min.js:2
wjquery-1.7.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using an iframe to make it works, as the result of the google test page is a complete html page.

Your code becomes :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
         $('.stats-data').html('<center><img src="css/img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loader_IMG" /><br>Rendering your stats</center>');

         $('.stats-data').attr('src', 'stats-render.php');
       });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe width="600" height="600" class="stats-data">
      override me
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

It loads the content of the google cahrt in your page using an iframe.
If you really wanted to use a div instead of an iframe, you should consider parsing the result of your ajax call and fill your div correctly.

Comment: For some reason it doesnt work, i will add here two files and with you may see the problem better, there is test.php that have your code and demo.php with a very simplified version of the stats-render, as you will see, if you open demo.php it works, but if you try to open it from test.php it wont. DEMO.PHP: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/5pGs36l4Y7
TEST.PHP: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/XpGhnsF3uZ

Comment: It works for me, as it is exactly the same files I test.
What is your error this time ?

Comment: It is really weird, I have exactly your files, and it works for me. Maybe you are missing something out of the problem.